# Adding BooleanField to django model ,this field for existing items should be True, for new items it should be False

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to add a setting checkbox to a Django model, for this reason, I am adding BooleanField to one of the existing django models, this boolean field should be True for all the existing rows in the database, However, the field should be False for new rows created.

```
class FlagSetting(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)# by setting default to 'False' disabled the flag for the existing entries as well
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Anything to do with overriding the `save()` method?

**EDIT** I am looking for a solution which respects automated production deployment. Thank you all for helping me out

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: The default value in your model is not only used when saving new instances but also used in the migration to give a value to the new column. You can add an additional migration where you update all existing rows in your table to have the flag set to True.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the existing behavior of the `flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)` so that it satisfy my current requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are many options on how to handle this situation. One would be to first simply add the field without a default value and ask Django to create the appropriate migration. So your model should look like:

```
class FlagSetting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    flag = models.BooleanField()
```

When you run the command `manage.py makemigrations` Django will ask what to do, you can choose to provide a 'one-off default value'. This value will be used to populate existing instances. By doing this the migration code generated by Django will set your provided one-off default value to all previously existing instances.

Afterwards you should change your model again in order to set the desired default value for your field so your model looks like:

```
class FlagSetting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And then you have to run `manage.py makemigrations` again. This time a new migration will be created to set the default value to `False`. Then every newly created instance is going to have `flag=False` by default.

Comment: Posted and seen that there was already a very similar answer from @Alassdair

Comment: If you have automated deploys, having Django ask you what to do on a migration isn't very handy. It's useful on your development environment where you can quickly test things, but whenever you see this question asked by Django, you should fix your migrations so you won't have this during a production deploy.

Comment: As far as I know when Django asks for a 'one-off value' this value is stored in the migration, as a matter of fact I've tried an example like the one in this answer and ended up with the following migration:

    migrations.AddField(
            model_name='model',
            name='test',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
            preserve_default=False,
        ). Therefore I don't see what the problem is with automatic deployment...

Answer (score 7):

Add the field with `default=True`, and run `makemigrations` to create a migration. Then switch the default to `False` and run `makemigrations` again.

Then run `migrate` to run both migrations. When the first migration runs, Django will add the column and set all existing entries to `True`. The second migration won't change the value for existing rows.

With this approach, I think you'll end up with a small window between running the migrations and restarting your webserver where creating a new row through the website would cause a 'not null constraint failed'. If this is unacceptable, then you can create the field with `null=True`, run the migrations, then remove `null=True` and run a final data migration to change any nulls to `True` or `False` as required.

Comment: thank you for the answer, the code is set for automated production deployment, any solution without stopping the server

Comment: The first approach might work well enough in practice. If not, I think you’ll need to migrations/deploys that add the field with `null=True`, then a second deploy afterwards to tidy up.